# How Composer/Airflow to skip the time-sensors automatically when we do the backfill?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

Does anyone know how to do backfill for Airflow DAG?

I'm try to backfil a DAG for 1-2 months data back, but when I used the below command, that every-time I need to mark as success the sensor manual. This not make any sense.
1. **Does anyone have a good suggestion?**

```
gcloud composer environments run leo-stage-bi --location=europe-west1 backfill -- player_daily_balance_type_snapshot    -s 20190222      -e 20190401 -t  bq_daily_type_snapshot_malta  --reset_dagruns
```

[image]

Comment: You can mark them as success by filtering the tasks in the Web UI (Browse > Task instances : [...].appspot.com/admin/taskinstance/?flt2_operator_contains=ExternalTaskSensor). You can add additional filters and bulk select the tasks you want to mark as success. I think this is possible to do via the command-line too, but I can't test it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the short investigation that i was found the a method to skip the time-sensors!

```
  -i, --ignore_dependencies
```

**Upstream tasks, run only the tasks matching the regexp. Only works in conjunction with task_regex**

**Default: False**

References:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli.html

Comment: Oh, didn't see you found something suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli.html#backfill), there are some optional arguments that may help you.
You could try using the flag `-m` (`--mark_success`)

> Mark jobs as succeeded without running them
>
> Default: False

Please let me know if it helps you